# Пресс-формист или прессформист?

Tags: словообразование, орфография, слитно-дефис

С пресс-формой все ясно, в справочнике Лопатина с этим словом все однозначно.
А как быть с человеком, который эти пресс-формы делает, и помещением, где этот самый процесс происходит?
Пресс-формист или прессформист?
Пресс-формистская или прессформистская?
Логично, что написание через дефис сохраняется, но есть какое-то сомнение

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Практически чаще встречается  слитное написание: прессформист, хотя пресс-форма.

ПРЕСС-ФОРМА,  [нем. Pressform] Спец. Приспособление для изготовления изделий путём прессования. Пресс-форма — сложное устройство для получения изделий различной конфигурации из металлов, пластмасс, резины и других материалов под действием давления, создаваемого на литьевых машинах.

Можно предположить, что семантика слова связана не только конкретно с пресс-формой,  но и с работой на сложном оборудовании, где используется давление для получения нужной формы изделия. Тогда и словообразование не стоит жестко привязывать к "пресс-форме".

Прессформист - это рабочий, обслуживающий литьевые машины, на которых под действием **давления**  получают **изделия сложной конфигурации** (с использованием пресс-форм).

Кстати, довольно часто можно увидеть слитное написание "прессформа", которое, как мне кажется, больше подходит к современному производству.

Answer (score 0):

Если допустить что Лопатин не погорячился, фиксируя дефисное написание у "пресс-формы", ошибочно смешав её с "пресс-папье",  то дефис надо сохранять.

На самом деле дефисное написание большинства слов с "пресс" подчеркивает, что их значение связано напрямую с прессом, а не с процессом (прессования, прессовки). Пресс-папье - это устройсво, которое является прессом и хранилищем для бумаг.  В отношении работника такое несколько странно (он же не есть "пресс", он "прессовщик" поэтому логично слитное написание. Точно так же исходное "пресс-форма" не являющаяся по своей сути прессом, а только используемая в процессе прессовки, должна бы, в отличие от "пресс-папье" иметь слитное написание.

Но "что выросло - то выросло". Зафиксировано дефисное написание, поэтому пусть будет "пресс-форма". Но в таком предположении уже нет причин переносить этот поход на производные (такое случается, не всегда производные от слов с дефисным написанием его сохраняют, но это отдельная тема).

Так что я за "прессформист" (и даже "прессформовщик") , хотя и не уверен в стопроцентной нормативности оного.